# How to write the Path of a file to window upload file and press enter to upload with command line or autoit

Tags: windows, batch-file, upload, command, autoit

I'm trying to create a batch file or autoit to paste path of a file to window upload file when it shows and press enter upload. But no ideas and no ways on google.

[image]

Comment: Possibly this may help: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/12/create-script-in-autoit-to-upload-file.html

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste in autoIT with [`ClipPut()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ClipPut.htm):

```
; CTRL + C
ClipPut($pathname)

; CTRL + V
Send("^v")

; Hit ENTER
Send("{ENTER}")
```